# Return of pointer with unaccessible address with overloaded operator +

Tags: c++

I have found a lot of discussions about this error, however nothing I have tried worked so far.

Basically I am creating a templater vector class using a dynamic array, however when I tried to overload the "+" operator, it only works with 2 addends (v3=v1+v2), when I tried 3 addends(v4=v1+v2+v3), it returns the last addend (v3). I have found out that this is because when the function that overloads + operator is called 2nd time, the pointer of the first addend has value 0xcccccccc. That means that it is probably poiting to something that does'nt exist anymore. However, I don't know how should I return the vector object from the overload function. This is what I have tried, but none of these works:

```
//this works only for two addends
template <class T> Vector<T>& operator+(Vector<T>& v1, Vector<T>& v2)
{
    Vector<T> v;
    //calculations
    return v;
};

//this causes above mentioned error
template <class T> Vector<T> operator+(Vector<T>& v1, Vector<T>& v2)
{
    Vector<T> v;
    //calculations
    return v;
};

//this causes above mentioned error too
template <class T> Vector<T> operator+(Vector<T>& v1, Vector<T>& v2)
{
    Vector<T>* v= new Vector<T>;
    //calculations
    return (*v);
};
```

Any idea how to return vector object so it would work with 3 addends as well?

Comment: The first version is always broken (returning reference to local variable, undefined behaviour), the third is kind of broken because it requires the caller delete the return value, and the second one is almost OK, but needs `const` reference parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `const` references so they can bind to temporaries:

```
template <class T> 
Vector<T> operator+(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
{
  Vector<T> tmp = v1;
  tmp += v2;
  return tmp;
}
```

If your types are efficiently movable, you can use rvalue reference oveloads to leverage that:

```
template <class T> 
Vector<T> operator+(Vector<T>&& v1, Vector<T>&& v2)
{
  Vector<T> tmp = std::move(v1);
  tmp += v2;
  return tmp;
}
```

Obviously, you should not return a reference or something that needs to be deleted by the caller.

Comment: Oh, yeah it required couple of modifications in my class, since I haven't used 'const' almost anywhere. Thanks